# Can I make a circuit that work on either 220VAC or 12VDC from the same input?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc

I want to make a sort of protection circuit that if someone plugged a 12V DC lamp into 220VAC it will still work.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible ... it is available off the shelf ... it is called `power adapter`

Comment: @jsotola I don't think so. Sounds like the op wants a magical box that will guess and provide the specs of the load plugged in. Any load. The OP should clarify - the title is asking A, but the body is asking B.

Comment: you cannot directly plug a 12 V load into a 220 Vac power outlet unless you have made a dangerous modification to the power plug ... if you do make such a modification, and someone gets hurt, then you must assume full responsibility and accept any consequences

Comment: Please clarify your question and what you meant by "work". You said you need a "**protection** circuit", but also that when "someone plugged a 12V DC lamp into 220VAC it will **still work**". If it's a protection circuit, it can simply protect the lamp from exploding by detecting the high voltage and killing the power input, so it will not "work" in the sense that the lamp outputting light. If you need to both protect the lamp and simultaneously provide power, the protection circuit should also act as a power supply, which will be considerably more complex and convoluted.

Comment: Why would a 12 V lamp have a 220 V plug on it?

Comment: Do you care about the size and weight of the solution?  Do you care about the efficiency?

Comment: There are plenty of LED drivers out there that will take 12 to 220V input with little more than a bridge rectifier and capacitor for AC.  In theory, as long as you were driving a string of LEDs that needed less than, say 10V, you could put 12VDC in and it would still work.  You'd just need to design for safety at 220VAC and be sure that your LED driver wouldn't overheat.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Not easy, but certainly possible. If this doesn't seem like a useful answer, it's because it's not - but you asked a yes/no question.

Comment: @brhans Can't think of any solution not involving some kind of AI :)

Comment: @vir _"There are plenty of LED drivers out there that will take 12 to 220V input ..."_ - I doubt it. Can you name one?

Comment: @EugeneSh. _"Sounds like the op wants a magical box that will guess and provide the specs of the load plugged in. Any load. The OP should clarify - the title is asking A, but the body is asking B."_ - I disagree; both title and body seem to be asking for a circuit that will drive a 12VDC load, but will take either 12VDC or 220VAC input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the same input for AC and DC power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519094/using-the-same-input-for-ac-and-dc-power)

Comment: _" if someone plugged a 12V DC lamp into 220VAC"_ - how could they do that?

Comment: The problem with this type of question is, that it's a yes or no question. And that the level of knowledge the asker seems to have is a beginner's. It would be necessary to include some years of lecture and some whole books on circuit design to properly explain the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MXHV9910 from IXYS will run on 8-450VDC:
https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/0/713EA18902B59CCF85257566004FAD55/$file/MXHV9910.pdf

Comment: He also needs AC

Comment: Fig. 5 shows a universal AC input configuration.  If you over-specced the bridge rectifier and perhaps made a few adjustments to combat flicker at high supply voltage I don't see why DC applied to the input of the bridge wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Best with something relatively low power (a couple watts or less) since efficiency won't be excellent at either extreme.

I recall some industrial timer type devices from the usual Japanese suspects (eg. Omron, Idec, National etc.) that could do this.